# Created element is overwritted JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript, loops

In a JavaScript loop I want create multiple A elements.
I wrote some code but I get only one element because the element is overwritten.

```
var create_tag_a_elm = document.createElement("a");
var create_article_elm = document.createElement("article");
for(const tag in Newsid.tags){
    create_article_elm.appendChild(create_tag_a_elm).innerHTML = tag;
}
```

What do I need in my code to get more A elements like

```
<article>
    <a>tag 1</a>
    <a>tag 2</a>
    <a>tag 3</a>
</article>
```

Comment: You are appending _the same `<a>` element_ every time, essentially moving it, because appending it elsewhere will remove it from where it was before. Create a new one in each iteration, then you won't have this problem.

Comment: You can use `.cloneNode` to clone the element

Comment: Move the assignment of `create_tag_a_elm` inside the loop so you create a new element each time.